# SQL get info from 2 tables and compare

Tags: php, sql, compare

I have 2 tables that I want to compare and find the users that the username is not following and then display the username of the person not being followed.

```
Edit:
Table 1: users 
username

Table 2: follow
username (the name of the user)
followname (the name of the person the user follows)

In Table 2 username and followname are never null.  When a user follows another user then it is put into the list like so:

Username          Followname
derekshull         dvdowns
derekshull         testuser
dvdowns            testuser
testuser           1511project
derekshull         newuser
```

In my head I see table 1 getting a list of all the usernames (column name is "username" from table 1) and then gets a list of all the usernames the user ($username) is not following (column name is "followname" from table 2).

How do I make it compare the two lists and not display the usernames the user is following already?

Here's what I have right now.  For some reason it is displaying users that I follow and don't follow.

```
$alluserslookup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username!='$username'");
$thefollowerslookup = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM follow WHERE username='$username'");

while ($followersrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($thefollowerslookup)) {
$afollower = $followersrow['followname'];

while ($allusersrow = mysql_fetch_assoc($alluserslookup)) {
$allusers = $allusersrow['username'];

if ($afollower != $allusers) {
echo "<a href='viewprofile.php?viewusername=$allusers'>$allusers</a><br>";
}
}
}
```

Comment: Have You heard about [`LEFT JOIN`](http://google.com/?q=LEFT+JOIN) or [`JOIN`](http://google.com/?q=SQL+JOIN) itself?

Comment: I have not.  How would that help?

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html for an explanation of how it should be used in MySQL, and my answer for an example of how it can be used in this situation. (Are you using MySQL?)

Comment: Can you provide the column names of your tables?

Comment: I added an edit in the post to show how the tables are set up.

Comment: Basically I'm take a list of all "username"'s from table "users   --->   taking a list of all the "followname"'s where "username" == "$username" from table "follow"    ---->  Then displaying only the names that don't appear in both lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Updated) Try:

```
select u.* from users u
left join follow f on u.username = f.followname and f.username = 'derekshull'
where f.followname is null
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/932ef/3).

Comment: check the edit I just added.  I think it will give more clarity.  I plugged in your code and it didn't work.

Comment: I take that back...something is working but it's not showing the user names.  Could you take a look and see why that may be?  I put it in the original post.

Comment: @derekshull: updated - my earlier version included a bunch of columns that would have been null.

Comment: Basically I'm take a list of all "username"'s from table "users   --->   taking a list of all the "followname"'s where "username" == "$username" from table "follow"    ---->  Then displaying only the names that don't appear in both lists.

Comment: @derekshull: I had the relationship between user and followname the wrong way round - try now (and see the example on SQLFiddle). You may also want to exclude the user themselves.